# Create an Isometric Grid

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

i am trying to create a Isometric grid and I am not very good with math, I have tried to make a conditional on the odd numbers, but it does not give me the expected result

This is an example that I want to get

[image: img]

````js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
const cols = 8
const rows = 8

const PI = Math.PI
const TAU = PI * 2

const particles = []
const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight
const radius = 5
const offset =  width / cols

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

const init = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

      const x = j * offset
      const y = i * offset
      
      particles.push({
        x,
        y
      })
    }
  }
}

const update = () => {
  particles.forEach(particle => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(particle.x, particle.y, radius, 0, TAU)
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  })

  window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

init()
window.requestAnimationFrame(update)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Let we define distance between point `D` (perhaps your `offset`)

You can make y spacing equal for all rows, it is `D/2`

X-spacing is `D*sqrt(3)`, and x-shift depends on row, for even ones it is `D*sqrt(3)/2`, for odd ones it is 0.

Code might loo like this: ( I am not very familiar with JS)

```
const SQ3 = Math.Sqrt(3)
const SQ32 = Math.Sqrt(3) / 2
...
const D = offset   

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

     const y = i * D / 2
     const x = j * D * SQ3 + (1 - i % 2) * D * SQ32
  
  particles.push({
    x,
    y
  })
}
```

Comment: I managed to get an isometric grid, but now I would have to give 8 points for each row and column, any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/alain075/mab6so82/37/